# Prove that the subset W of M2, consisting of all matrices of a form is a subspace of M2.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem in my textbook:

Let M2 be the vector space of all 2 x 2 matrices.

(i) Prove that the subset $W$ of $M2$ (the set of all 2 x 2-matrices), consisting
of all matrices

$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$

with $a + b + c + d = 0$ and $a - b + c - d = 0$ is a subspace of $M2$.

(ii) Find a basis for $W$.

Prove your answers.

(Hint: the set $W$ is a null space in $R4$ ' $M2$ of an appropriate 2x4 matrix.)

I have put  a + b + c + d = 0 and and a - b + c - d = 0 in a system, to get $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\a & b\end{bmatrix}$, but I am lost from there.

Comment: Flatten the matrices, using $M_2\cong\Bbb R^4$. Also, I think $a$ and $c$ can be arbitrary, need not coincide.

Comment: For (i). What is the definition of a subspace? Try to show that $W$ satisfies that definition. For example $W$ needs to be closed under scale multiplication. Take a scalar $\lambda \in K$ where $K$ is the field over which the vector space is defined. Now let $M\in W$ with entries $a,b,c,d \in K$. So $\lambda M$ has entries $\lambda a, \lambda b, \lambda c, \lambda d$. Then $0 = a+b+c+d = \lambda\cdot(a+b+c+d) = \lambda a + \lambda b + \lambda c + \lambda d$ and $0 = a-b+c-d = \lambda \cdot(a-b+c-d) = \lambda a - \lambda b + \lambda c - \lambda d$. Therefore $\lambda M \in W$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
Check that the map $\begin{aligned}[t]f:\mathcal M_2 &\longrightarrow K^2\qquad (K\text{ is the base field})\\\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}&\longmapsto (a+b+c+d, a-b+c-d)\end{aligned}$ is linear, and observe $W=\ker f$.